# Restrict a build step for a job name or user

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to restrict a build step for a user. I have added a build step using the templates plugin, this template is for the deployment.

I do not want any users who has access to create a job or modify a job to be able to use this build step. The new build step that has been added should only be used by the the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If people can modifying Job configuration, they *can* get around any limitation you would place.

If your step can be executed post-build, I suggest to take a look at [**Promoted Builds**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) plugin. The promotions can be configured to be limited to certain users only. But again, if a user has ability to change job configuration, they *can* overcome that easily.

The only way I can think of, is to have an external script (or preferably a compiled program than cannot be simply "read" with text editor) that is expecting a password that only you now, before executing whatever secret stuff that you want.